# Java Enum<T> vs T as variable type

Tags: java, generics, enums, difference

Is there any difference between this declaration

```
Thread.State state = Thread.State.NEW;
```

and that

```
Enum<Thread.State> state = Thread.State.NEW;
```

in Java? Instead of the second option is a bit longer?

Comment: Same difference there is between, for example, AbstractList and ArrayList. If you need to access members specific to ArrayList, and not present in AbstractList, your variable needs to be declared as ArrayList. The first one here is more concise, clearer, and idiomatic. You're not gaining anything by using the superclass, because there will never be any other subclass of Enum<Thread.State> anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two practical differences (as opposed to language-lawyerly reasons) that come to mind:

1. If you declare `state` as an `Enum<Thread.State>`, then you won't be able to pass it to any methods that expect a `Thread.State`.
2. If you declare `state` as an `Enum<Thread.State>`, you'll leave the reader — whoever needs to touch this code in the future — wondering why you've written it that way.

Neither of these is a terribly deep reason; we could easily imagine a parallel universe where most people used `Enum<Thread.State>` instead of `Thread.State`, just as (in our universe) most people use `List<...>` instead of `ArrayList<...>` (when possible). But since most people *don't* do that in our universe, you're better off just following the common pattern, to minimize the risk of confusion and accidental incompatibility.

---

Incidentally, in case this is going to be your next question . . . the main situation where you *would* use `Enum` is when you want to write something generic that works for many different enum types. An example of this in the JDK is [`EnumMap<K extends Enum<K>,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html), which is a special map implementation that gets space and performance benefits out of knowing that its keys are enum values.

(And note, incidentally, that you *can't* write `EnumMap<Enum<Thread.State>, String>`, because `Enum<Thread.State>` doesn't extend `Enum<Enum<Thread.State>>`. Instead, you *must* write `EnumMap<Thread.State, String>`. So this is an example of difference #1 that I mentioned above: if you declare `state` as an `Enum<Thread.State>`, then you can't use it as a key in an enum-map.)

Answer (score 13):

It's the same case as comparing between:

```
Child o = someChild;
```

and

```
Parent o = someChild;
```

`Enum` is the parent class of all enum types. Therefore, with the second line, the code cannot contain references to specific members of `Thread.State`, specifically the members described in [this section of the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3).

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any difference ....

In practice, in this particular case, probably no.

In theory, `Thread.State` is a subtype of `Enum<Thread.State>`.  If `Thread.State` declared (non-private) fields or methods, then you could use them via the first declaration of `state`, but not the second one.

In general, the first form is preferable ... for that reason.

---

Also, I don't think you would be able to see an enum's `static` methods `values()` and `valueOf` via the variable declared in the second declaration; e.g.

```
state.valueOf("BLOCKED")
```

However, calling a static method via an instance reference is bad style.